# CTAN : raw datas for user

Tags: ctan

I would like to add in my long CV (not my short CV) the list of package I maintain in CTAN.

Is there somewhere a file where I could make a request, to:

- obtain the list of package I am associated
- have some information for each package : maintenance status, name, short description.

For example an XML file?

Comment: you mean like http://www.ctan.org/author/carlisle ?

Comment: yes, but i a most structured file. Like xml/json/bib... because I am afraid to have to change my code if the html presentation changes someday

Comment: the source is available from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue

Comment: sorry, I didn't see where are the datas about package in .xml format.

Comment: http://sarovar.org/frs/?group_id=129&release_id=219

Comment: actually that may not be the latest version, hmm :-)

Comment: yes ... I saw that ...

Comment: you can browse the cvs entry for each package, http://sarovar.org/plugins/scmcvs/cvsweb.php/texcatalogue/entries/c/calc.xml?rev=1.16;content-type=text%2Fx-cvsweb-markup;cvsroot=texcatalogue;only_with_tag=MAIN

Comment: That looks great. But must I browse all the csv to find the package from one author ?

Comment: the python scripts in the repository generate the html author page at the start of this thread from the xml files there so in principle you could modify that to generate any format you want.

Comment: Ok, so no one central file by author. I will look for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the cvs links look like old too. For example I don't find the eledmac package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just published an experimental feature on the CTAN portal to retrieve information about the catalogue in XML form. This includes cross references for authors. For instance:
[http://www.ctan.org/xml/au­thor/knuth?ref=true](http://www.ctan.org/xml/author/knuth?ref=true)

The [online help](http://www.ctan.org/help/access) provides some details.

Comment: A warm welcome! Can you change your user name to something fancier than `user43912`? `;-)`

Comment: that look exactly what I need ! a great thank !

Comment: just an other question ? I was thinking that the ctan should be ask by mirror.ctan.org. Is it true for this also ?

Comment: CTAN provides different services. The file download is distributed to the mirrors. Others like searching and access to the catalogue (HTML or XML) are provided by the central server only.

Comment: thanks. For your information, I was able to use your file to answer to my problem. Cf http://contrib.spip.net/Donnees-CTAN-4487 (in french, sorry)

Answer (score 17):

<sup>Great, I should be sleeping by now, but **no**, I had to code something! `:)` Somebody please call the authorities.</sup>

Here goes my pathetic attempt to provide the raw data you want. Since I had no idea of a good name (namely *bird names*, of course), I wrote a small application called `ctaninfo`. Here it comes:

```
paulo@alexandria ~$ java -jar ctaninfo.jar
```

And then we have:

[image: Quack 1]

The author ID is the short name CTAN gives us, for example, `cereda` for me, `gregorio` for egreg and `carlisle` for David. You guys probably know what I'm talking about, right? `:)` Now let's try:

[image: Quack 2]

Then we click the OK button (don't mind the localization stuff, since my Linux is in Portuguese; you guys will probably get the window in your current locale). And wait. And wait a lot. Did I mention we have to wait? `:)`

<sup>Specially if you are David. Oh boy, he has *a lot* of packages! `:)`</sup>

If things don't get messed up, we will probably reach this final screen

[image: Quack 3]

and we will have a file named `<author ID>.xml` lying somewhere in our computer, hopefully in the same directory the application is. `:)` In my example, we have `rouquette.xml`:

```xml
<ctan>
  <packages>
    <package>
      <title>bibleref-french – French translations for bibleref</title>
      <description>The package provides translations and alternative typesetting conventions for use of bibleref in French.</description>
      <sources>
        <string>/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref-french</string>
      </sources>
      <documentation>
        <string>Package Manual</string>
        <string>Package Manual</string>
      </documentation>
      <versions>
        <string>2.3.1</string>
      </versions>
      <licenses>
        <string>The LaTeX Project Public License 1.3</string>
      </licenses>
      <copyright>
        <string>2012 Maïeul Rouquette and Raphaël Pinson</string>
      </copyright>
      <maintainers>
        <string>Maïeul Rouquette</string>
        <string>Raphaël Pinson</string>
      </maintainers>
      <distributions>
        <string>TeXLive as bibleref-french</string>
        <string>MiKTeX as bibleref-french</string>
      </distributions>
      <topics>
        <string>typeset devotional texts and other material of interest to theologians</string>
      </topics>
    </package>

    ...

  </packages>
</ctan>
```

I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/cereda/ctaninfo) for `ctaninfo`, and the binary can be found [here](https://github.com/cereda/ctaninfo/releases/tag/1.0), under the *releases* link. Phew. `:)`

*Up the wooden hill to Bedfordshire!*

Comment: that is a great think. Thanks very much. But, as I could see in the code, you take the information from the .html webpage, which structure could change. So I think it don't solve the main problem. A second point is that, in my case, I would like to make request automatically with PHP... so your tools is useful for local use, but not if we want to make automatically request.

Comment: @Maïeul: Thanks! I wrote this humble code in 10 minutes, I guess. `:)` You are right, I retrieve data from the HTML page, parse and then serialize into an XML file, so if things change in the future, I might get into trouble. `:)` I think the best option is then kindly ask the CTAN gentlemen to include some sort of web service or even statically generated `.json` file with the author metadata.

Comment: yes, that is why I was thinking. But I don't know if the CTAN gentlemen have time ...

Answer (score 10):

there is a read-only copy of the
  catalogue source, omitting author details at `rsync://rsync.tex.ac.uk` for use with rsync.  (the author details contain email addresses, so we decided simply to omit them.  for the same reason, we can't simply publish our svn pointer -- that remains protected.)

the copy is updated daily.

(nb, i *tried* to use the facilities provided for urls in answers, but the formatting insisted on putting http: before the rsync: )

Comment: Yay, that's great, R... I mean, wasteofspace! `:)`

Comment: it's great ... but there is still the problem of no information about author :-(